# Trying to get Parent container inrease in height with contents

Tags: html, css

### **PART 1:**

I am trying to make my parent div increase with height as the contents. it is a slide show contained in a parent div and the slide show is responsive. Everything sits fine but 10px padding is not reflected around the main container. Any help?

#### **Example:**

```css
.mainer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px
}

.slide_wrapper {
  width: 60%;
  height: inherit;
  top: 10px;
  border: 0px solid black;
  clear: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainer">
  <div class="slide_wrapper">
    <div class="carousel_slider">
      <div class="item" style="width:100%;">
        <img src="image.jpg" style="width:100%;height:auto" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

### **Part 2:**

(Bonus for me.)

Assuming that I am also trying to include a different div `class="rightbox"` to the right of the container `class="carousel_slider"`. Both of them have to stay inside the main container. How can I achieve this? Part 2 is just a curiosity for me.
Any help?.
Thanks and appreciation in Advance.
**Michelle**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem might be related to using a clear without a clearfix. I'm not entirely sure why you have `clear:left` to begin with really, you don't have any other floated elements to clear in your html. Anyhow, when you clear an element, it no longer takes up space normally. The item **within** the cleared element will still take up space, but you can't apply margins and padding normally to a cleared element without clearfix. Here's one you can use easily.

http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

That being said, clear + clearfix is fairly depreciated and you may find better results elsewhere. Try making .mainer relatively positioned, and absolutely position .slide_wrapper inside of it. That should allow you to set the width to 60% still and align it relative to the top and left of .mainer. Perhaps look into flexbox if you aren't using old versions of internet explorer. I'm not going to explain all of flexbox here as other's have already done it and better, but it allows you to align items intelligently to their parent container and is particularly helpful if you element has siblings.

Answer (score 0):

`padding: 10px` on the parent is being applied, but you have `top: 10px` on the `img` that is pushing it down 10px and messing up the bottom padding of the parent. To increase the space between the top of the image and the parent without messing up the bottom padding of the parent, use `padding-top` or `margin-top` instead of `top` on the `img`

And to put `.rightbox` beside of `.carousel_slider`, make the parent `display: flex` and it will put those 2 children in adjacent columns in a row.

```css
.mainer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
}

.slide_wrapper {
  height: inherit;
  border: 0px solid black;
  clear: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
.slide_wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
}
.rightbox {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainer">
    <div class="slide_wrapper">
     <div class="carousel_slider">      
        <div class="item" style="width:100%;">
          <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" style="width:100%;height:auto"/>
        </div>       
      </div>
      <div class="rightbox">rightbox</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Micheal coker. Thanks Mike. Stupid of me with the padding on img. Thanks. it worked. but on the part 2 it also worked but i tried giving a width and height to the right box, it does reflect it. i instead out the right div outside the slide-wrapper and gave the mainer a flex display it kind of worked well but the right div floated too far to the right. leaving too much distance from the slider

Comment: @MichelleDimwaite you're welcome. re: the rightbox, all you said was you wanted a rightbox to the right. If you want to assign a height and width, use `align-items` on the flex parent and set it to something other than `stretch` so you can change the height. You can use width on that just fine, but it's probably limited by your `width: 60%` on the parent which will limit the potential width of the children. I removed `width: 60%` and added `justify-content: center` to the flex parent to center the image and rightbox. Updated my answer with those changes.

Comment: @Micheal Coker: thanks thanks Thanks. It worked just well Mike. I taught justify-content was similar to text-align. Great work and thanks again...Michelle